# How to build GNUstep programs on OpenBSD?

Tags: gnustep, openbsd

I am trying to build a GNUStep program on OpenBSD. I installed packages gnustep-base and gnustep-make.

my main.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void)
{

    NSLog(@"Hello World!");  
    return 0;
}
```

GNUmakefile:

```
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make
TOOL_NAME = main
main_OBJC_FILES = main.m
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make
```

Then, I initialize the GNUstep environment using

```
. /usr/local/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
```

And then I run:

```
make
```

This does not recognize the GNUmakefile.

Does anybody know how I can build a GNUstep program on OpenBSD?
On my Arch Linux installation, similar procedure works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `make -f GNUmakefile`. If this command fails, install `gmake` and try `gmake -f GNUmakefile`.

Comment: Thank you. From OpenBSD's Misc mailing list, I came to know that BSD system's make is different from GNU make. And I need to use gmake for that. It worked!